# How do I use a bolean to stop one music while the other plays

Tags: javascript, html, audio, boolean

I have two meditation music that play and stop with a button using js. The problem is that if one is played, the other also plays when clicked.

I want one to stop playing when the other is clicked. I am learning about Boolean values. Is there a way to do this using boolean values?

```
<div class="main-box">
  
<div class="slot1"> 
  
<p class="line line1">this is the long music</p>

<audio id=rollSound loop>
  <source src="sounds/long-medi.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="sounds/long-medi.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the sound files. Please proceed by using other solutions.
  <!--the obove text will only show if the users' browser does not play the two files. -->
</audio>
<button id=play>play/stop</button>

<script>
const rollSound = document.getElementById('rollSound');
const btn = document.getElementById('play');

btn.addEventListener("click", e => rollSound.paused ? rollSound.play() : rollSound.pause());
                                                                    
</script>
</div>



<div class="slot2"> 
  <p class="line line2">this is for short music</p>

  <audio id=shortsound loop>
  <source src="sounds/short-medi.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="sounds/short-medi.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the sound files. Please proceed by using other solutions.
</audio>
<button id=roll>play/stop</button>

<script>
const shortsound = document.getElementById('shortsound');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('roll');

btn2.addEventListener("click", e => shortsound.paused ? shortsound.play() : shortsound.pause());



</script>

<script>
const rollSoundEl = document.getElementById('rollSound');
const shortsoundEl = document.getElementById('shortsound');
const btn = document.getElementById('play');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('roll');

function playOneSound(soundToPlay, soundToPause) {
    soundToPlay.paused ? soundToPlay.play() : soundPlay.pause()
    soundToPause.pause()
}

btn.addEventListener("click", () => playOneSound(rollSoundEl, shortsoundEl));
btn2.addEventListener("click", () => playOneSound(shortsoundEl, rollSoundEl));

  </script>

</div>
  




</div> <!--main-box-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare variables

```
const rollSoundEl = document.getElementById('rollSound');
const shortsoundEl = document.getElementById('shortsound');
const sounds = {shortsound: shortsoundEl,rollsound: rollSoundEl}
const btn = document.getElementById('play');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('roll');
```

Write logic

```
function playOneSound(soundToPlay, soundToPause) {
    const soundEl = sounds[soundToPlay]
    const soundToPauseEl = sounds[soundToPause]
    soundEl.paused ? soundEl.play() : soundEl.pause()
    soundToPauseEl.pause()
}
```

Implement logic

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => playOneSound('rollsound', 'shortsound'));
btn2.addEventListener("click", () => playOneSound('shortsound', 'rollsound'));
```

---

***Alternative Way***

Declare variables

```
const rollSoundEl = document.getElementById('rollSound');
const shortsoundEl = document.getElementById('shortsound');
const btn = document.getElementById('play');
const btn2 = document.getElementById('roll');
```

Write logic

```
function playOneSound(soundToPlay, soundToPause) {
    soundToPlay.paused ? soundToPlay.play() : soundPlay.pause()
    soundToPause.pause()
}
```

Implement logic

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => playOneSound(rollSoundEl, shortsoundEl));
btn2.addEventListener("click", () => playOneSound(shortsoundEl, rollSoundEl));
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's a [link to a working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elements-as-function-parameters-ygx2i?file=/src/index.js).

I think the reason it didn't work is because i made a typo earlier:

soundToPlay.paused ? soundToPlay.play() : **soundPlay.pause()**

Should be:

soundToPlay.paused ? soundToPlay.play() : **soundToPlay.pause()**

**P.S.**

Due to (new-ish) browser specifications, one must first refresh the page before he or she is able to play sounds that are embedded in the page.

Comment: This works great thankyou so much. Can I please know why there is a sounds variable and why are they declared like this?  couldn't you have used shortsound and rollsound instead of naming new ones?

Comment: I'm glad my solution suits you, the sounds object is being used for dynamic accessing to the sound elements. basically it let's you send to the function only the name as argument instead of the entire element. You could definitely do that too.

Comment: I added an alternative way to write the code according to your suggestion. Feel free to choose either one.

Comment: I can't thankyou enough for this. I understand the alternative version better, however it doesn't work like expected.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? you can edit your question with updated information after the changes and i'll do my best to help.

Comment: I managed to produce a working example from the code you provided according to your requirements. Please review my last edit.

Comment: I fixed the typo in my real code but not the one edited here. Please take a look.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inconvenience but I couldnt find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236173/discussion-between-dandan-drori-and-heleni).